# Matrix in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

would you please help me solve this question?
$A$, $B$, $C$ are matrices.

if $AB = AC = I$ and  $BA = CA = I$, show that $B=C$

I think we can't use inverse matrix for this problem.

A,B,C are in the same size and square.
if we want to use the Binet theorem,we don't need extra information that AB=AC=I ,... ,just this condition was required to solve this question.thank you.

Comment: If you do not think you may use inverse matrix, then what should we use? What method is it that you want applied and how would you apply it?

Comment: Does $I$ refer to the identity matrix? if so, you're saying that $AB = BA = AC = CA = I$?

Comment: Are these square matrices?  @SiddharthBhat If they're not square, then the identities are different sizes.

Comment: @MichaelBurr - however, if $AB = I$ __and__ $BA = I$, then we can conclude that $AB = BA$ and they must be the same size, correct?

Comment: @SiddharthBhat Sure, that would work (by a rank argument).

Comment: Since $AB=AC=I$, $0=AB-AC=A(B-C)$.  Now, if we multiply on the left by $B$, we have $0=BA(B-C)=I(B-C)=B-C$, so $B=C$.

Comment: I think that the identities matrix have different size, otherwise the answer is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially uniqueness of the inverse:

Note that $B = B(AC) = (BA)C = C$.

You wrote that you can't use the inverse matrix for this problem - in fact, $B$ *is* the inverse of the matrix.

Comment: Yes.But now we don't know the concept of inverse matrix and related theorems.

Comment: Yes, that's doesn't matter. What you wrote down is the very definition of the inverse, so you do not know any theorems about the inverse matrix (e.g. how to compute then algorithmically).

Answer (score 0):

Since $AB=AC=BA=CA=I_n$ it's easy to see that the matrices are square. Then you can use the Binet theorem to prove the statement in this way:

$$det(I)=det(AB)=det(A)det(B)=1;$$

so $det(A)$ and $det(B)$ must be different to zero. n particular $A$ is invertible and the conclusion follow.

Comment: hi,I forgot to write that A,B,C are in the same size and square.

Comment: if we want to use the Binet theorem,we don't need extra information that AB=AC=I ,... .just this condition was required to solve this question.thank you.

Comment: if the matrices have the same size the condition $BA=CA=I$ is useless.

Comment: why it is useless?

Comment: if $AB=I$ then $B$ is the inverse of $A$, in other words: $B=A^{-1}$ and by basic algebra $AA^{-1}=A^{-1}A=I$