# If $BA = I$, prove that $AB = I$ (using determinants)

Tags: matrices, proof-verification, determinant

I've seen this problem around here, but I wanted to check if this particular solution is right.

So, if $BA = I$, then $det(B)det(A) = 1$, meaning neither $det(B)$ or $det(A)$ are equal to $0$. Because $det(B) \neq 0$, $B$ must be invertible, which means $CB = I$ for some matrix $C$.

Next, consider $CBA$.

$BA = I$, so $CBA = C(I) = C$.

$CB = I$, so $CBA = (I)A = A$

$CBA = C = A$. Now knowing that $C = A$, I can substitute $A$ in for $C$ to get $CB = AB = I$, which is what I wanted to prove.

Comment: You got it, pal

Comment: You needed the determinants only to ensure that the matrices are invertible. In the proof, you did not use them. So, the title is slightly misleading.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matrix in linear algebra](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1762578/matrix-in-linear-algebra)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quicker argument. You know $A$ and $B$ are invertible, so $$ABA = A$$ implies $AB = I$ by multiplying $A^{-1}$ on the right. However, your argument is correct.

Edit: After thinking about this more, I think the point of the original exercise is to prove that every square matrix with a left inverse also has a right inverse and vice versa. I suppose this can be done just from properties of the determinant. In that setting, all of the arguments presented so far are circular.

Comment: this also holds up even if the matrix $A$ is non-invertible by considering a matrix $P$ such that $APA = A$. $P$ is called  the pseudo-inverse of $A$ and is a pretty neat mathematical object. [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse)

Comment: This is almost exactly the same argument except written with fewer words.

Answer (score 1):

No determinants required really (I suppose $A,B$ are square matrices): if $BA=I$, $A$ is the matrix of an *injective* endomorphism, and $B$ the matrix of a *surjective* endomorphism. However, in finite dimension, injective $\iff$ surjective $\iff$ bijective. Hence $A$ and $B$ are invertible, and inverse to each other. Thus  $AB=I\implies BA=I$.